# Is this Matrix Indefinite or Positive Semi Definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, optimization, hessian-matrix

Consider the following matrix:

$ A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1\\ 
1&1&1\\ 
1&1&0
\end{pmatrix} $

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=0$, $\lambda_2=1-\sqrt{3}≤0$ and $\lambda_3=1+\sqrt{3}≥0$.

But when computing the principal minors we obtain:

$A_1=1≥0$

$A_2=\begin{vmatrix} 1&1\\  1&1 \end{vmatrix} = 0$

$A_2= \begin{vmatrix} 1&1&1\\ 1&1&1\\ 1&1&0 \end{vmatrix} = 0$

So all leading principal minors are ≥ 0, but we have two eigenvalues with different sign and the third one is zero... Im really confused, thank you!

Comment: You should prove to yourself that if a symmetric PSD matrix has zero on the $k$th diagonal entry *then all elements in row/column k must be zero* -- this is violated here.  Checking leading principal minors is not enough for symmetric PSD -- you need to check *all principal minors*. I gave a proof here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4145638/a-is-positive-semidefinite-iff-textdet-b-k-geq-0/

Comment: @user8675309 I've also found this other [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/551422/505767)

Comment: The matrix is symmetric, and it has eigenvalues of different signs. So, it cannot be positive definite, or positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for the minor at the bottom right

$$\begin{vmatrix} 1&1\\  1&0 \end{vmatrix} = -1$$

therefore by [Sylvester criterion](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Emlavrov/docs/484-spring-2019/ch1lec5.pdf) the signature is $(1,1,1)$ according to the sign of eigenvalues you have determined and the matrix is then indefinite.

---

Refer also to the related

- [Deducing that a matrix is indefinite using only its leading principal minors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/551422/505767)
- [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1817906/505767)